# Two linked lists having shared element

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, software-design

If I have two linked lists, how do you know if they have a common element without looking at their data? doesn't matter which language to implement that, what Im asking is on the approach/the algorithm for solving my problem.

Appreciated if there's a good optimal approach.

thanks

Comment: What does "without looking at their data" mean? Without inspecting the elements of the lists it is certainly impossible to find out if they have an element in common.

Comment: What do you mean by "common element"?  If you mean "both contain the same value" then you have to look at data.  If you mean "meet" then run through each to the last node.  If the last nodes are the same, then they met at some point.

Comment: You need to explain through some examples because your requirement isn't clear

Comment: @btilly yes, but what do you mean? didn't understand you well, I mean didn't understand the logic behind your approach for my problem.

Comment: @LiamLony if the two lists meet at some point, then they stay the same after that point. In particular, the address of the last element must be the same for the two lists.